# Skewed / Off-axis stereoscopic projection with glm::frustum flickering

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glm-math

[image: slide from Simple, Low-Cost Stereographics]
[image: flicker]

I have a 3d, stereoscopic rendering application that currently uses parallel stereoscopy by just moving (shifting) the camera to the side for each Left and Right views. It does work, but recently I felt it could be much improved if I had the off-axis option. I got a semi-working algorithm for glm::frustum() to allow for this but am having some troubles immediately when I switch to it over glm::perspective().

I followed the only GL guide I could find, [Simple, Low-Cost Stereographics](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/SVEN/sigcse04-handout.pdf), that which said to replace my existing glm::perspective() with (2 calls

```
//OFF-AXIS STEREO
if (myAbj.stereoOffsetAxis) {
    glm::vec3 targ0_stored = i->targO;

    if (myAbj.stereoLR == 0)
    {
        float sgn = -1.f * (float)myAbj.stereoSwitchLR;

        float eyeSep = myAbj.stereoSep;
        float focalLength = 50.f;
        float eyeOff = (sgn * (eyeSep / 2.f) * (myAbj.selCamLi->nearClip->val_f / focalLength));
        float top = myAbj.selCamLi->nearClip->val_f * tan(myAbj.selCamLi->fov->val_f / 2.f);
        float right = myAbj.aspect * top;
        myAbj.selCamLi->PM = glm::frustum(-right - eyeOff, right - eyeOff, -top, top, myAbj.selCamLi->nearClip->val_f, myAbj.selCamLi->farClip->val_f);

        i->targO += myAbj.selCamLi->rightO * myAbj.stereoSep * (float)myAbj.stereoSwitchLR;
        VMup(i);
        i->targO = targ0_stored;

    }

    if (myAbj.stereoLR == 1)
    {
        float sgn = 1.f * (float)myAbj.stereoSwitchLR;

        float eyeSep = myAbj.stereoSep;
        float focalLength = 50.f;
        float eyeOff = (sgn * (eyeSep / 2.f) * (myAbj.selCamLi->nearClip->val_f / focalLength));
        float top = myAbj.selCamLi->nearClip->val_f * tan(myAbj.selCamLi->fov->val_f / 2.f);
        float right = myAbj.aspect * top;
        myAbj.selCamLi->PM = glm::frustum(-right - eyeOff, right - eyeOff, -top, top, myAbj.selCamLi->nearClip->val_f, myAbj.selCamLi->farClip->val_f);

        i->targO += myAbj.selCamLi->rightO * -myAbj.stereoSep * (float)myAbj.stereoSwitchLR;
        VMup(i);
        i->targO = targ0_stored;
    }
}
```

Using this equation, my View Matrix is rotated 180 degrees on the Z axis. However, the bigger issue is a large amount of black dots and flickering on my objects. When I move the camera to a close enough point the flickering stops. Even when I minimize the scene, the issue is still there.

**Why is this flickering happening and what can I do to prevent it? It is ruining my scenes.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My near clip was causing the problem. It couldnt be set to the same low value that glm::perspective() was using - it needed a little bit more.